# How to edit the flappy_search_bar flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to edit some features of the [flappy_search_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/flappy_search_bar#-readme-tab-)

[image]

As you see see the loading spinner is blue and I can't seem to edit this to any alternate color. I also am unable to edit the cursor color which is also blue.

Here is a copy of my current code block:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SearchBar<Post>(
          searchBarPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          headerPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          listPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          onSearch: _getALlPosts,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
          hintText: 'Search',
          iconActiveColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
//          cursorColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
//          loader: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
            fontSize: 18.0,
          ),`
```

So far, I have tried editing directly within the search bar as seen above, adding extension code as follows:

```
 class Styling extends SearchBar {
  Styling(this.cursorColor);
  final Color cursorColor;
  static const accentColor = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
//      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
//        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
//      ),
        );
  }
}
```

I have also tried editing the package files directly but this hasn't been a success either.

Has anyone suggest how to edit the cursor color and loading spinner color of the flappy_search_bar package?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do this too and managed to get it done.

To edit your cursor, apply the following to your top level MaterialApp under `ThemeData` :

```
cursorColor: Colors.red,
cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
),
```

This sets the color of the Cursor in *ALL* TextFields , I don't know how to edit it just for the TextField in the `flappy_search_bar` widget

For the loading indication, add this under the `SearchBar` you're using:

```
SearchBar<SomeClass>(
....
loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red))),
....
);
```

This is what the widget does internally if you look at the source. 
Change `Colors.red` to whatever color you need.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying! The loader now loads in the color needed. I am still unable to edit the cursor in the SearchBar textfield. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to update the cursorColor in your MaterialApp under `ThemeData` as shown above? That's what worked for me!